# Google Map Area of Interest exported to Polygons

Tags: polygon

Is there a way to export the yellow shaded areas of interest in Google Maps as polygons. I am only interested in England and primarily only really interested in High Streets Towns & Cities, i.e. retail areas.

I have looked everywhere for alternative data and it doesn't seem to exist, postcode zones wont work for me as I'm only really interested in retail areas for a university project I am working on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStreetMap can do this for you (via QGIS **OSM Downloader**)
https://www.geodose.com/2020/08/how-to-download-osm-data-qgis.html

[image]

And classified the data by 'other tags'

To show Retail (Landuse)

[image]

Comment: WOW.. perfect. That's great thanks for the pointer